# Why is jurabib setting et al. in authors font, even if it belongs to editors?

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

The goal is to differentiate between authors and editors by highlighting authors with bold face and leaving editors in standard shape. Jurabib describes the commands ´bibfnfont´ and ´biblnfont´ for authors and ´bibefnfont´ and ´bibelnfont´ for this purpose. According to my understanding I was setting them to:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibefnfont}{\textnormal}
\renewcommand*{\bibelnfont}{\textnormal}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\textbf}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@BOOK{Gerichtsschreiberamt,
  title = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei am Reichshofgericht},
  year = {1974},
  editor = {Bernhard Diestelkamp and Ulrich Eisenhardt and Gunter Gudian and Adolf Laufs and Wolfgang Sellert},
  author = {Friedrich Battenberg},
  series = {Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich, Reihe~B: Forschungen, Band~2},
  address = {K\"oln},
  shorttitle = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei}
}

@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Handw\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Gerichtsschreiberamt}. Test2\footcite{Lehnswesen}.

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

The result is fine in terms of the first and last names, but the et al. which belongs to the editors, not the authors, is printed in bold:
[image]

Comment: Jurabib seems really outdated. I always thought about having a look into biblatex. There is a very up to date translation into German and the text refers even to some differences of Jurabib, see here: https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/info/translations/biblatex/de/biblatex-de-Benutzerhandbuch.pdf . So what about BibLaTeX for your project?

Comment: If the project would be kicked-off at this time, I'd absolutely agree, but it is close to finisihing. Hence a change is no option. Are you the developer of jurabib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jurabib uses the same command for the etal of authors and editors. So there is no official interface. You can try the following patch but be aware that it can have side effects on other entry types. I extended the one author list for the test:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibefnfont}{\textnormal}
\renewcommand*{\bibelnfont}{\textnormal}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\textbf}

%reset font patch:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\bibenf{\renewcommand\bibfnfont{}}{}{\fail}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@BOOK{Gerichtsschreiberamt,
  title = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei am Reichshofgericht},
  year = {1974},
  editor = {Bernhard Diestelkamp and Ulrich Eisenhardt and Gunter Gudian and Adolf Laufs and Wolfgang Sellert},
  author = {Friedrich Battenberg},
  series = {Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich, Reihe~B: Forschungen, Band~2},
  address = {K\"oln},
  shorttitle = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei}
}

@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge and A Muster and B Max and C Min and D Author},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Handw\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Gerichtsschreiberamt}. Test2\footcite{Lehnswesen}.

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well with that approach the first visible side effect is that et al. is added to the author (behind Auge, Oliver) which is technically correct, but not content-wise.

Comment: No, the et al after the author is there because I extended the author list for the test as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yes, what I meant as well: This is now technically correct (as there are multiple authors in the bib-file), but content-wise it is incorrect, because there is only one author for this incollection

Comment: Yes, what I meant as well: This is now technically correct (as there are multiple authors in the bib-file), but content-wise it is incorrect, because there is only one author for this incollection

Comment: Well this are test bib entries, no real bib entries.

Comment: Sorry @Ulrike Fischer, now I see the `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\bibenf{\renewcommand\bibfnfont{}}{}{\fail}`. I was so fixated on the output and the changed bib entries. Thanks for this quick-fix, I will use and take care.

Comment: I added another complication: No authors, but only editors in combination with bibformat=tabular

Comment: No, don't extend or change questions. This is only confusing. Make a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83215/discussion-between-tobibs-and-ulrike-fischer).