# et al. still printed bold by jurabib with bibformat=tabular and no author at all

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

With the workaround by @Ulrike Fischer at [Why is jurabib setting et al. in authors font, even if it belongs to editors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450987/why-is-jurabib-setting-et-al-in-authors-font-even-if-it-belongs-to-editors) I was able to solve the initial problem to the largest extent. But in combination with `bibformat=tabular` and the bib-entry:

```
@BOOK{Findebuch_1,
  title = {Findebuch zum mittelhochdeutschen Wortschatz},
  year = {1992},
  editor = {Kurt G\"artner and Christoph Gerhardt and J\"urgen Jaehrling and Ralf Plate and Walter R\"oll and Erika Timm},
  volume = {1},
  address = {Stuttgart},
  shorttitle = {Findebuch~1},
  volumetitle = {a\,--\,êvrouwe}
}
```

which leads together with Ulrike's proposed changes, to:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibformat=tabular]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibefnfont}{\textnormal}
\renewcommand*{\bibelnfont}{\textnormal}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\textbf}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\bibenf{\renewcommand\bibfnfont{}}{}{\fail}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@BOOK{Gerichtsschreiberamt,
  title = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei am Reichshofgericht},
  year = {1974},
  editor = {Bernhard Diestelkamp and Ulrich Eisenhardt and Gunter Gudian and Adolf Laufs and Wolfgang Sellert},
  author = {Friedrich Battenberg},
  series = {Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich, Reihe~B: Forschungen, Band~2},
  address = {K\"oln},
  shorttitle = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
@BOOK{Findebuch_1,
  title = {Findebuch zum mittelhochdeutschen Wortschatz},
  year = {1992},
  editor = {Kurt G\"artner and Christoph Gerhardt and J\"urgen Jaehrling and Ralf Plate and Walter R\"oll and Erika Timm},
  volume = {1},
  address = {Stuttgart},
  shorttitle = {Findebuch~1},
  volumetitle = {a\,--\,êvrouwe}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Gerichtsschreiberamt}. Test2\footcite{Lehnswesen}. Test3\footcite{Findebuch_1}

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

you still see a bold et al. as there is no author where the hook could play its game:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to patch `\biblenf` - and for good measure probably also `\bibrenf` and `\biblrenf`.

I also found it slightly nicer to redefine `\bibIMfont`, the font command that typesets "et al." and friends, to `\bibEIMfont` instead of redefining the lower-level `\bibfnfont`. As Ulrike remarked in her answer to your linked question, `jurabib` uses the same command (the author font command `\bibIMfont`) for "et al." and a few other strings. With `\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibIMfont}{\bibEIMfont}` we change that from the author to the editor fonts.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibformat=tabular]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\bibefnfont}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibelnfont}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\textbf}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\bibenf  {\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibIMfont}{\bibEIMfont}}{}{\fail}
\xpretocmd\biblenf {\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibIMfont}{\bibeimfont}}{}{\fail}
\xpretocmd\bibrenf {\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibIMfont}{\bibeimfont}}{}{\fail}
\xpretocmd\bibrlenf{\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibIMfont}{\bibeimfont}}{}{\fail}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@BOOK{Gerichtsschreiberamt,
  title = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei am Reichshofgericht},
  year = {1974},
  editor = {Bernhard Diestelkamp and Ulrich Eisenhardt and Gunter Gudian and Adolf Laufs and Wolfgang Sellert},
  author = {Friedrich Battenberg},
  series = {Quellen und Forschungen zur h\"ochsten Gerichtsbarkeit im alten Reich, Reihe~B: Forschungen, Band~2},
  address = {K\"oln},
  shorttitle = {Gerichtsschreiberamt und Kanzlei}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Lehnswesen,
  author = {Oliver Auge},
  title = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen},
  booktitle = {Hand\-w\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,717\,--\,736},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  shorttitle = {Lehnrecht, Lehnswesen in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
@BOOK{Findebuch_1,
  title = {Findebuch zum mittelhochdeutschen Wortschatz},
  year = {1992},
  editor = {Kurt G\"artner and Christoph Gerhardt and J\"urgen Jaehrling and Ralf Plate and Walter R\"oll and Erika Timm},
  volume = {1},
  address = {Stuttgart},
  shorttitle = {Findebuch~1},
  volumetitle = {a\,--\,êvrouwe}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Gerichtsschreiberamt}. Test2\footcite{Lehnswesen}. Test3\footcite{Findebuch_1}

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```